# How to use Chrome's network debugger with redirects

Tags: http, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The Chrome network debugger gives me a great view of all the HTTP resources loaded for a page. But it clears the list whenever a new top-level HTML page is loaded.  This makes it very difficult to debug pages that automatically reload for one reason or another (running script or 300 responses).

Can I tell Chrome not to clear the network debugger when a new top-level page is loaded? Or can I go back and look at the previous page's network resources?

Or can I somehow force Chrome to pause before loading a new page when I don't control the page I'm trying to debug that's doing the redirecting?  It's part of an OpenID dance that's going awry, so the combination of SSL and credentials makes it extremely difficult to debug with command-line tools.

Comment: @Pacerier The one you linked doesn't appear to be posted by you, but the reasoning is likely that it doesn't have "Chrome" in the title. When people are looking for something related to Chrome their search usually includes the keyword Chrome. "Google Developer Tools" is incredibly ambiguous.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/InstanceOfMichael/f6a509b84fe82a718816

Answer (score 687, accepted):

*This has been changed since v32, thanks to @Daniel Alexiuc & @Thanatos for their comments.*

---

**Current** (≥ v32)

At the top of the "Network" tab of DevTools, there's a checkbox to switch on the "Preserve log" functionality. If it is checked, the network log is preserved on page load.

[image: Chrome v33 DevTools Network Tab: Preserve Log]

The little red dot on the left now has the purpose to switch network logging on and off completely.

---

**Older versions**

In older versions of Chrome (v21 here), there's a little, clickable red dot in the footer of the "Network" tab.

[image: Chrome v22 DevTools Network Tab: Preserve Log Upon Navigation]

If you hover over it, it will tell you, that it will "Preserve Log Upon Navigation" when it is activated. It holds the promise.

Comment: In version 32 it's still there, but has moved to the top of the network panel.

Comment: Actually, it's now at the top, but called "Preserve log", and is a checkbox. Confusingly, there's still a red record icon, but that's just whether to log at all.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on the change, I just updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @ruben, the interface does indeed now look a bit different, but there's still a checkbox labeled "Preserve log" at the top of the network tab: http://i.imgur.com/fhSDYSz.png

Comment: @boundaryfunctions I know, I've been using it for a few weeks, but yesterday I updated Chrome to version 43.0.2357.65 and it doesn't work the way it used to anymore. Now the request that produces the redirect is replaced by the next request, I have to be very quick to click on the first request to see the details before it disappears. Can you check this behavior with your latest version of Chrome? To be clear, all previous request are preserved in the log, but the one that produced the redirect disappears.

Comment: @ruben Sorry, I can't confirm this problem for version `43.0.2357.81 (64-bit)` on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @rubenlop88 Make sure you're not filtering on *Documents*, otherwise they won't persist there. You can check them specifically in the *Other* tab.

Answer (score 236):

I don't know of a way to force Chrome to not clear the Network debugger, but this might accomplish what you're looking for:

1. Open the js console
2. `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false)`

This will pause chrome before loading the new page by hitting a breakpoint.

Comment: This wasn't the right answer for the question, but it's actually what *I'm* looking for. Thanks.

Comment: This is so slick. I got here looking for a "pause before redirect" solution and here it is. The accepted answer is easier to remember but this is rad.

Comment: This is extremely useful, because chrome does not shows the server response body, if the browser redirects right after getting the response.

Comment: This is useful, but I still do not see the <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0;url=/somewhere/over/the/rainbow"> tag in the response. I need to investigate how the redirect is done, and I still do not have access to the reponse before the redirect...

Answer (score 59):

Another great solution to debug the Network calls before redirecting to other pages is to select the `beforeunload` event break point

This way you assure to break the flow right before it redirecting it to another page, this way all network calls, network data and console logs are still there.

**This solution is best when you want to check what is the response of the calls**

[image: Chrome beforeunload event break point]

P.S:
You can also use XHR break points if you want to stop right **before** a specific call or any call (see image example)
[image: XHR break point]

Comment: This is great. With the `load` event, we can stop at the beginning and set break point easily. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me just by ticking the checkbox. The javascript snippet window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() { debugger; }, false) is necessary.

Comment: No, it's not. I'm using it daily.

Comment: "This solution is best when you want to check what is the response of the calls" Preserving not just the request data while being redirected from one site to another, but also the response data is exactly what I need. Four years have past since your post and a seemingly obvious feature such as having the network trace capture and keep the raw response data still isn't supported?

Answer (score 26):

Just update of @bfncs answer

I think around Chrome 43 the behavior was changed a little. You still need to enable Preserve log to see, but now redirect shown under Other tab, when loaded document is shown under Doc.

This always confuse me, because I have a lot of networks requests and filter it by type XHR, Doc, JS etc. But in case of redirect the Doc tab is empty, so I have to guess.