# JavaScript event log

Tags: javascript, logging, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events, firefox-developer-tools

Is there any way to see which events are being executed with JS.

For example, let's assume I have click event being fired, and then keypress...Now I want to have a log of those fired events.

Is there a way I can get such log of fired events (possibly with function names, but that is optional)?

EDIT:
I think I need to add a detail to this. I want to log all events. If there is some custom event that I am not aware of, I want to know its name. For that reason I can not monitor only certain events that I am aware of, but also those that I am not.

EDIT 2:
Log should only contain events for elements on which certain listener is attached. E.g. via `$('#test-element').on(...)` or `testElement.addEventListener(...)`. Again, names of events are unknown (don't have to be click/keypress/...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log javascript errors in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401094/log-javascript-errors-in-chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle a click anywhere in the page, even when a certain element stops the propagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054429/how-do-i-handle-a-click-anywhere-in-the-page-even-when-a-certain-element-stops)

Comment: Maybe this is what you are after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213703/how-do-i-view-events-fired-on-an-element-in-chrome-devtools

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is proposing a monitoring function that you can use : [monitorEvents](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/quickly-monitor-events-from-the-console-panel)

If I remember correctly, the following javascript line should log everything:

```
monitorEvents(document);
```

If you want to only watch specific events, you can use the second argument:

```
monitorEvents(document, 'click');
```

You are of course free to replace document by any object you want to watch.

Comment: Is there a way to call this only for registered event listeners. For example for $('#test').on('click', ....) or testElement.addEventListener('click', ....). 
It seems like this solution fires for every event called, which is understandable, but I want it to be fired for every registered event.

Comment: I edited the answer with a little more info, you can find full documentation folowing the link in my answer.

Comment: Just as a note, `monitorEvents()` was originally implemented in Firebug. There's also a [feature request to implement it into the Firefox DevTools](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1165138).

Answer (score 2):

Fill Array with listners you want to attach and then log their type;

```
['click','onkeypress'].forEach( evt => 
        element.addEventListener(evt, log, false)
);

log = (event) => {
    console.log(event.type)
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question a bit since I think it misses an important detail. I cannot hardcode which evets to monitor. I need to monitor all of existing events. Even those I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
    var oldListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
    EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted ){
        const oldEventHandler = listener;
        listener = function(event){
            EventTarget.log = EventTarget.log || [];
            EventTarget.log.push("day? hour? minute? "+type);
            oldEventHandler(event);
        }
        oldListener.call(this, type, listener, useCapture, wantsUntrusted)
    }
```

And then type EventTarget.log in console

Answer (score 1):

To log the event on click (replace window with the exact event target):

```
window.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Element clicked?");
  });
```

To log enter keypress:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
    let key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) { // 13 is enter. you may use other numbers for other keys
     console.log('Enter pressed');
   }
});
```

To log all events use the array:

```
['click','mouseover', 'keypress'].forEach(ev => {
    window.addEventListener(ev, () => {
        console.log('event:', ev)
    })
})
```

List of available events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Logs can be seen in the browser console (F12)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are events I am not aware of so I can not hardcode events :/

Comment: In such way just do not use conditions (all keys will be logged) and leave window object. Like   window.addEventListener('keypress', e => {
     console.log('Enter pressed');
});

Comment: I've expanded my reply a bit

Answer (score 0):

What I fond useful is Firefox Dev Tools. When inspecting an element you have a label "event". By clicking on the label you can see events attached to the element.

[image]

Comment: This shows which event listeners are attached to a specific element, though that doesn't tell you which of them actually get called.

Answer (score -1):

Use `console.log("Your text");`

You will see this output by pressing `F12` on your browser, on the `console` section.