# I am getting an error while loading a PDF in my app with the library github.barteksc.pdfviewer

Tags: java, android, pdf, github, logcat

This is the error I am having in my logcat

```
E/PDFView: load pdf error
     java.io.IOException: cannot create document: File not in PDF format or corrupted.
         at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.nativeOpenMemDocument(Native Method)
         at com.shockwave.pdfium.PdfiumCore.newDocument(PdfiumCore.java:126)
         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.InputStreamSource.createDocument(InputStreamSource.java:37)
         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:53)
         at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Who told you that that library will display pdf's from internet? And why did you not tell that you used an internet url?

Comment: Really ? How do I use internet URL then.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was reported in [barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer issue 175](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/issues/175)

> Had the same error. For some reason reading PDF directly from assets did not work, and gave the above mentioned error.
>
> So copied it from asset to cache dir, and then all worked.

But first, double-check you can open that PDF file (independently of your execution environment, outside of your Java program).

Comment: my app is not created with the intention for reading PDFs form asstets folder , I am getting it from internet with URL link.

Comment: @AkshayRaut Did you test that link (independently from your Android environment) to see if there is a pfd behind said link?

Comment: Yes!  my link is open and it runs on both pc and my android. I did test the pdf link in another browser of my android and it opens.

Comment: @AkshayRaut With the network panel of a chrome devtool (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network), can you check if that link goes through redirection (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282621/6309)? Maybe the library does not follow properly those URL redirection?