# Chrome Dev Tools: Viewing original request details in 301 redirect

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, http-status-code-301

I've noticed in Chrome's dev tools, when you make a request to a url that ends up returning you a 301 redirect the following happens:

1. The original request (a POST in this example) is written to the Network tab
2. The server returns a 301 redirect to a different URL
3. The original request details in the Network tab are overwritten with the redirect request, which is a GET request to the redirect URL

You can see the original request briefly before it is overwritten by the redirect. Is there anyway to preserve the original request details in the Network tab?

Update:
[Here's a video of the behavior.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1jt3ff9vbvota9d/Select%20Devices%20-%20Google%20Chrome%202020-05-11%2021-27-01.mp4?dl=0)

You'll see when I hit the "Connect" button a new entry is added to the list of requests (to "/acl?apiKey=[whatever]"). When the server returns a redirect (to "/redirect?code=[whatever]") that requests **overwrites** the original request in devtools, making it impossible to see the details of that original request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Chrome's network debugger with redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987453/how-to-use-chromes-network-debugger-with-redirects)

Comment: @wOxxOm: No, that's just how to preserve the network history on navigation. I've updated the post with a video and explanation of the behavior I'm talking about.

Comment: In that case the only way is probably to use `chrome://net-export`